# GCM server returns null value

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement Google Cloud Messaging in my app. Still i can't figure out why i don't get the correct message to my phone. My server sends a message, GCM servers respond to to that and send a message back to my phone.This message looks like this

```
{\"multicast_id\":8186678237008516542,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1356727074650189%12aaaeccf9fd7ecd\"}]}"
```

I think that means that i get a message, the problem is my app only shows null value. I am using the Browser Api key right now and get these results, but I have tried to use server key(which theoretically is more suitable to my needs), but i get Error 401.

For receiving the message, i use a broadcast receiver

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);}
```

EXTRA_MESSAGE = message

This is the code i use in my server.

```
$fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
```

Does anybody know what the problem might be??

Comment: Where exactly are you showing that null value?

Comment: The null value is returned to the android application in the emulator

Comment: Don't you think including information as the code that is displaying the problem or the logcat trace for the exception would be important?

Comment: Try logging out the contents of the intent so that you can see what is being sent to your application via the message. Also post the contents of your onMessage() method.

Answer (score 1):

I think your response string name mismatch, So please check your response string name. I have used it as "price" in my server side code and in my android side code.you can see it in below images.

File at server side : send_message.php

[image]

File at application side : GCMNotificationIntentService

```
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

public static final String TAG = "GCMNotificationIntentService";

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                    + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                .equals(messageType)) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }

            }
            sendNotification("Message Received from Google GCM Server: "
                    + extras.get("price"));
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    //Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gcm_cloud)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    //Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adjust your code from

```
'data' => $message,
```

to be something like this:

```
'&data.message=' => $message,
```

and your onMessage() method in GCMIntentService should be something like below:

```
protected void onMessage(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String message =intent.getStringExtra("message");;

    }
```

Comment: Make sure you are catching the intent in onMessage() as was pointed out, instead of your onReceive() method.